# combining a filter and a query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to do a search with elasticsearch 5.1.1 to look for the word "construction" anywhere and filter the results with either phase1 or phase2 on the "phase" field.
I tried many things which all fail.
Here is a sensible one:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/books/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {"filter": {"terms": {"phase": ["phase1", "phase2"]}}, "query": "construction"}
  }
}'
```

Error:

```
parsing_exception
no [query] registered for [filtered]
```

Also note that the phase field might have a value like "Phase1/Phase2" so I need to see whether it contains Phase1 or Phase2.
How can I perform such a search?

---

update

@volodymyr, the following works:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/books/_search?pretty=true" -d '{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":{    
               "multi_match":{  
                  "query":"construction",
                  "fields":["title"]
               }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

with a result like

```
  {
    "_index" : "books",
    "_type" : "gov",
    "_id" : "2296112",
    "_score" : 5.742423,
    "_source" : {
      "description" : "",
      "countries" : [
        "United States"
      ],
      "phase" : "Phase 2",
      "completion_date" : "2018-01-01",
      "references" : [ ],
      "keywords" : [ ],
      "id" : "2296112",
      "title" : "Mainland construction"
  }
```

then I tried adding the phase and it is not failing but returns no results so this is still no good:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/books/_search?pretty=true" -d '{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":{    
               "multi_match":{  
                  "query":"construction",
                  "fields":["title"]
               }
         },
         "filter":{  
            "terms":{  
               "phase":["phase1","phase2"]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

also tried:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/books/_search?pretty=true" -d '
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "term" : { "title" : "construction" }
      },
      "should" : [
        { "term" : { "phase" : "Phase 1" } },
        { "term" : { "phase" : "Phase 2" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

It returns no results.

Comment: You need to post our mappings to understand why its not returning

Comment: Well please update question and not answer :)

Comment: I posted a sample result below. Is there a documentation related to the scenario where phase is in either of the values in a list?

Comment: Yes i saw that, reason I ask to update question is that when some body else will come to this question he/she will not read answers they will start with question so that is why its a good idea to add more info to question

Comment: Perfect. It worked when I changed "phase":["phase1","phase2"] to "phase":["1","2"] so you're right. Thanks

Comment: it works but its not 100% right ;)

Comment: but you get an idea so you can develop better solution

Comment: @max, If you are looking for an exact match, don't analyze the "phase" field. Declare it as "keyword". See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html
And instead of looking for "phase1" why don't you look for the exact term "Phase 1"? Are you trying to filter or querying with full-text search?

Comment: @mayid I am looking at a case insensitive match in a list of possibilities which cannot be done with full text search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My fault i missed that you are using 5.1, in that version [filtered query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/query-dsl-filtered-query.html) is removed now and you should use bool instead

If you wish to search for construction then go with multi_match for instance

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/books/_search?pretty=true" -d '{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":{  
               "multi_match":{  
                  "query":"construction",
                  "fields":[  
                     "field1",
                     "OTHER_FIELD_IF_YOU_NEED"
                  ]
               }
         },
         "filter":{  
            "terms":{  
               "phase":[  
                  "phase1",
                  "phase2"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

For values "Phase1/Phase2" it should also work since this will be tokenized to [phase1, phase2], if you use default tokenzer on phase field, but if you will supply "Phase 1/Phase 2" then it will not since then it will be tokenized to [phase, 1, 2]

After your update. 
The problem is that you wrote phase1, phase2 but actually you have phase 2, this means that ES will tokenize Phase 2 to [phase, 2] and you try to search "phase2" which means that there is no match. You have option to make phase field [as keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/keyword.html)  and then you can search for "Phase 1", "Phase 2" but in case when you have "Phase 1/Phase 2" then ES will expect you to search for exactly the same, but you can split that field to be an array and when you index you will send ["Phase 1", "Phase 2"]

Comment: Thanks. Your second json gives me this error: parsing_exception, no [query] registered for [filtered]

Comment: Now i get this error: no [query] registered for [query]

Answer (score -2):

The filter need to be outside of the bool scope:

```
    curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/books/_search?pretty=true" -d '
{ "query":
  { "bool":
    { "must":
      { "multi_match":        
        { "query":"construction", "fields":   
            [ "field1",    
             "OTHER_FIELD_IF_YOU_NEED"
            ] 
        }             
      }
     }
   }, 
   "filter":
      { "terms":
        { "phase":
             [ "phase1", "phase2" ]
         }
     }
 }'
```

Comment: Also have a look here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html